# only approved column returned back on any relationship

Tags: laravel

i have table products.

i need make something in model only return product where approved is equal to 1

this my schema

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->unsignedInteger('quantity');
        $table->unsignedInteger('subcategory_id')
        ->references('id')->on('subcategories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->decimal('price');
        $table->decimal('discount_price');
        $table->decimal('super_discount')->nullable();
        $table->string('cover');
        $table->unsignedInteger('brand_id')
        ->references('id')->on('brands')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id')
        ->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->string('color');
        $table->string('size_id')->references('id')->on('sizes')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('rate');
        $table->enum('made_in',['turkey','china','egypt']);
        $table->string('serial');
        $table->boolean('approved')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unique(['name','size_id','color']);
    });
```

i hope this is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of **Global Scopes**

> Global scopes allow you to add constraints to all queries for a given
>   model. Laravel's own soft deleting functionality utilizes global
>   scopes to only pull "non-deleted" models from the database. Writing
>   your own global scopes can provide a convenient, easy way to make sure
>   every query for a given model receives certain constraints.
>
> Writing Global Scopes Writing a global scope is simple. Define a class
>   that implements the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope` interface. This
>   interface requires you to implement one method: apply. The apply
>   method may add where constraints to the query as needed:

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class ApprovedScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        return $builder->where('approved', 1);
    }
}
```

> There is not a predefined folder for scopes in a default Laravel
>   application, so feel free to make your own Scopes folder within your
>   Laravel application's app directory.
>
> Applying Global Scopes To assign a global scope to a model, you should
>   override a given model's boot method and use the addGlobalScope
>   method:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Scopes\ApprovedScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new ApprovedScope);
    }
}
```

> After adding the scope, a query to `Product::all()` will produce the
>   following SQL:

```
select * from `products` where `approved` = 1
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes)

Comment: thanks it works very well , 
but i just need ask one more question , what i if i want to get the data that approved is equal to zero ?

Comment: If you would like to remove a global scope for a given query, you may use the withoutGlobalScope method. The method accepts the class name of the global scope as its only argument:

Product::withoutGlobalScope(ApprovedScope::class)->get();